# How to create Google Calendar Quick Add feature in Java?

Tags: java, calendar, nlp

I am working on a school project that requires a little bit of Natural Language Processing. We have to implement a feature that is similar to Google Calendar Quick Add feature in Java.

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=36604

I have done some research on NLP and so far have not managed to successfully implement the feature using LingPipe.

Is there any other Java library than could help me implement this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes< I ve actually done this for [russian langauge](http://g-calendar.appspot.com/application/testmessage) via this [toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/)

Comment: Could you provide a clear instruction on how to install the dependencies?

Comment: If you familiar with maven, check this link http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/Maven.

Answer (score 0):

try [JChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic), the ruby port of Chronic